# Default checkbox in ui_component admin customer_form to true and checked?

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent, forms, checkbox

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-checkbox.html

devdocs says default value is false but there is no clue how to turn it to true.
Anyone know what to add in xml file to make it happen. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to set the default checkbox value in ui_component

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <field name="myCheckbox" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Enabled</label>
            <tooltip>
                <description translate="true">This is my checkbox's description</description>
            </tooltip>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="boolean">false</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="boolean">true</map>
                    </valueMap>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Let me know if you have any other issue with the code
Thanks

Comment: I've tried <item name="default" xsi:type="number">true</item> but it doesn't get it checked.

Comment: <item name="default" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> works. Edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @LongNguyen... Yes, you are right and I've updated my answer Thanks